# Task.Yield() versus Task.Delay(0)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Does `Delay(0)` always get inlined? In my experience, it does:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Test()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            Console.WriteLine("after Yield(), thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await Task.Delay(0);
            Console.WriteLine("after Delay(0), thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine("after Delay(100), thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Test().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a console app, thus the thread pool is used for continuation. The output:

```
Main thread: 11
after Yield(), thread: 7
after Delay(0), thread: 7
after Delay(100), thread: 6
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inside `Task.Delay`, it looks like this (the single parameter `(int)` version just calls the below version):

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (millisecondsDelay < -1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsDelay", Environment.GetResourceString("Task_Delay_InvalidMillisecondsDelay"));
    }
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return FromCancellation(cancellationToken);
    }
    if (millisecondsDelay == 0)
    {
        return CompletedTask;
    }
    DelayPromise state = new DelayPromise(cancellationToken);
    if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
    {
        state.Registration = cancellationToken.InternalRegisterWithoutEC(delegate (object state) {
            ((DelayPromise) state).Complete();
        }, state);
    }
    if (millisecondsDelay != -1)
    {
        state.Timer = new Timer(delegate (object state) {
            ((DelayPromise) state).Complete();
        }, state, millisecondsDelay, -1);
        state.Timer.KeepRootedWhileScheduled();
    }
    return state;
}
```

As you can hopefully see:

```
    if (millisecondsDelay == 0)
    {
        return CompletedTask;
    }
```

Which means it always returns a completed task, and therefore your code will always continue running past that particular `await` line.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it does. A check of the IL in reflector shows (among other logic):

```
if (millisecondsDelay == 0)
{
    return CompletedTask;
}
```

So yes, it will hand you back an already-completed task in this case.

Note that the implementation of `await` includes checks that ensure that an already-completed task doesn't cause an additional context switch, so yes: your code will keep running without pausing for breath here.

Returning an already completed task is a recommended trick when the answer is already known / available synchronously; it is also common to cache `Task`s for common result values.

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks to me like a handy way to create a non-generic [task in completed state](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18527377/1768303). Accepting Damien's answer as technically he was first :]

Comment: @Noseratio I think using something like `Task completed = Task.FromResult(true);` is better, because it is guaranteed to work. I think `Task.Delay(0)` is not required to return a completed `Task`.

Comment: @svick, I agree `Task.FromResult(true)` is more appropriate, but I still like `Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: 0)` as I can easily simulate both sync and async continuation just by changing `millisecondsDelay`. Do you think they might change this behavior? That'd look like a breaking change for me, giving the above code.

Comment: @Noseratio The documentation doesn't clearly say what exactly happens for `0`. And I think you can't really consider a change of undocumented behavior to be "breaking" (even if it breaks programs that rely on it).

Comment: Just to be clear -- a No-Op is not the same as an inlined function (did I misunderstand the question?) -- a function with multiple returns / if statements (as shown in either answer) will never be "inlined" by .NET.

Comment: Hi, just a question: can we always replace Task.Delay(0) with Task.CompletedTask? I think latter is clearer.

Comment: @Sheen No. You are not able to do so with .NET 4.5. `Task.CompletedTask` only available in .NET 4.6. But if you have access to it then of cause you should use it.

Comment: @Noseratio I personally prefer `Task.FromResult(0)` simply because it is slightly shorter (and probably the shortest) .