# Task.Delay(0) not asynchronous

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code (yes, I could be simulating JavaScript `setTimeout` api)

```
    async void setTimeout(dynamic callback, int timeout)
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeout);
        callback();
    }
```

It looks like for `timeout > 0`, the `setTimeout` works asynchronously wherein the control is returned back to the `callee` on `await` and `callback` is invoked after the task runs asynchronously. **BUT** when `timeout == 0`, the function behaves in a synchronous manner (code always run past the await line in the same thread without a context switch). On further digging, it turns out that `Task.Delay` is implemented to behave this way ([Task.Yield() versus Task.Delay(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527149/task-yield-versus-task-delay0/18527223#18527223))

Wondering if there is a way to make Task.Delay(0) asynchronous or an alternate solution to make my `setTimeout` function asynchronous when `timeout` is `0`? (*so that I could mimic JavaScript* `setTimeout` *functionality*) I see discussions on using `Task.FromResult(true)` or `Task.WhenAll`, but they don't seem to work.

Indeed I can use `Task.Delay(1)` instead of `Task.Delay(0)` but it does not look organic.

Comment: What are you looking for when you say you're looking for a "context switch"?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. If you delay for `0ms`, you're not really delaying. In fact, its neither synchronous nor asynchronous as it's essentially a no-op. There is literally ***no work*** to be done asynchronously, so it immediately returns.

Comment: Use `Task.Yield`. This will post the continuation to be handled however the TaskScheduler sees fit, which that other post demonstrates. If you want to force a new thread use `Task.Delay(timeout).ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: In regards to mimicking javascript functionality, you're going to have a rough time. As far as I'm aware, javascript is *completely* synchronous, and `setTimeout` essentially queues up the method at the end of the queue that the engine is processing (assuming `timeout=0`). Even *if* `Delay` did dispatch a thread for 0 timeout, it wouldn't behave the same was as javascript does.

Comment: @Rob I fully understand that the code will return immediately when `timeout` is 0 as there is no work to be done. But my question is help with emulating the JS `setTimeout` function in C#. **Not possible using Task.Delay** would be a perfectly fine answer to me :)

Comment: Hey @mikez, I will try your suggestion. Also what about spinning a timer and doing something like this ```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delayInMilliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += () => callback();
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();
```

Comment: What's wrong with using 1 instead of 0? `Task.Delay(1)` would behave essentially the same as you'd expect from 0 (as it is still less then smallest time quant) and exectution will be scheduled back to context (i.e. to UI thread for WinForms/WPF).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `Task.Delay(1)` works, but it does not look organic :( and I wanted to reach out to the community to probe other options!!!

Comment: Creating a timer for a 0 delay seems little wasteful but it would probably do what you want, although best to dispose it inside the tick event callback. You could also just put the callback inside a `Task.Run`   (possibly with ConfigureAwait(false)) on 0 delay.

Comment: @infinity, as long as you've mentioned JS `setTimer`, do you care about the threading model of this code? It all depends on the ambient synchronization context, and well may continue on a different thread after  `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: @infinity, you can also look at the source code too at [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5863), this is not a solution, just a tip to understand these behaviours

Comment: @Noseratio Ideally I would like it to continue on the same thread. Buyt wouldn't execution after `await Task.Delay()` continue on the same thread unless we set `ConfigureAawit` is set to `false` ?

Comment: @PhilippeParé Thanks for the pointer!!! I didn't know that such a thing existed!

Comment: @infinity, it will under WPF or WinForms, but anywhere else (with default sync. context) it will continue on a random pool thread, which most likely is going to be different from the original thread. You might like to look at something like [`AsyncPump`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason `Task.Delay(0)` does not run asynchronously is because the async-await state machine explicitly checks whether the task is completed and if it is, it runs synchronously.

You can try using [Task.Yield()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield(v=vs.110).aspx), which will force the method to return immediately and resume the rest of the method on the current `SynchornizationContext`. eg:

```
async void setTimeout(dynamic callback, int timeout)
{
    if(timeout > 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeout);
    }
    else
    { 
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    callback();
}
```

Comment: please fix your else part. its not completed. where is Task.Yield ? ;)

Comment: thanks, not sure what happened, it somehow got lost after I logged in.

Comment: This has a race condition that could still cause synchronous behavior if `timeout` is very low. I recommend using `await Task.Yield(); await Task.Delay(timeout);`.

Comment: why isn't callback an `Action`?

Comment: Main problem with `Task.Yield()` is that it is more like [`process.nextTick()` than `setImmediate()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15349865/429091). From the docs of [`Task.Yield()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): “The synchronization context that is present on a UI thread in most UI environments will often prioritize work posted to the context higher than input and rendering work.”.

Comment: can i use action instead of dynamic ? Can someone give an example about the usage of this function ?

Comment: @Aron he went javascript all the way :)